# how to detect enter with bash read?

Tags: bash

I have this script

```
while true
do
 size=`tput lines`
 size1="$(($size-15))"
 output1=$(banner)
 output2=$(getMSG)
 clear
 echo "$output1"
 echo "$output2"
 read -t 0.1 -s -n 1 -p "Message: >> $msg" msg1
 if [[ $msg1 == *"\r"* ]]; then
  msg="enter"
 else
  msg="$msg$msg1"
 fi
 sleep 0.01
done
```

It works fine but i need to detect if the enter key was pressed.
How can i do this?? none of my attempts have worked.

I've also tried checking if it something like `\n`, `\r` or `^M` in it but to no luck.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `read` isn't really designed to read specific keypresses. That said, `msg1` will simply be empty if Enter is pressed.

Comment: @chepner is there an alternative that you know of?

Comment: Alternative to what? I'm still waiting to here why you need to read specific keypresses in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read -N`.

```
[STEP 101] $ v=
[STEP 102] $ read -N 1 v
    <-- Press <ENTER>
[STEP 103] $ printf '%q\n' "$v"
$'\n'
[STEP 104] $
```

---

According to `help read`:

> **-N nchars**
>
> > return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless EOF is encountered or read times out, **ignoring any delimiter**